# In Nix, how can I build a package that has a Python post-install script?

Tags: nixos, nix

I'm trying to make a Nix derivation for [Foliate](https://github.com/johnfactotum/foliate/tree/1.5.3), and this is my first real derivation, so I don't really know what I'm doing yet.

[Here's what I have so far.](https://github.com/JonathanReeve/nixpkgs/blob/e6951005e5a4c63cca3af889f0fb59e228947fa6/pkgs/applications/office/foliate/default.nix) It builds and installs, but fails with this error:

```
Running custom install script '/build/source/build-aux/meson/postinstall.py'
Failed to run install script '/build/source/build-aux/meson/postinstall.py'
FAILED: meson-install
/nix/store/2b4cdbcs1xbqjna5dr4qrr1p9p9bgm98-meson-0.51.2/bin/meson install --no-rebuild
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
builder for '/nix/store/32vn9xlxlk9zb7vmpm90bz5i5qq59fjc-foliate-1.5.3.drv' failed with exit code 1
error: build of '/nix/store/32vn9xlxlk9zb7vmpm90bz5i5qq59fjc-foliate-1.5.3.drv' failed
```

I tried adding `python3` as a build dependency, but that didn't seem to work. What am I missing?

Also, is there any other way I can improve or simplify this derivation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This error occurs because the shebang of the file points to something like `/usr/bin/env`, which is not available in the Nix sandbox.

We typically solve this by calling `patchShebangs` on the file in the `postPatch` section.

Sometimes the file is not executable so you might need to make it so; it is not a problem [here](https://github.com/johnfactotum/foliate/blob/1.5.3/build-aux/meson/postinstall.py) though.

```
postPatch = ''
  chmod +x build-aux/meson/postinstall.py # not necessary here
  patchShebangs build-aux/meson/postinstall.py
'';
```

Also note that we already have an (incomplete) [PR adding Foliate](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/pull/64536), you might want to take a look at that.

Comment: Thanks! I'd wondered how shebangs were handled. Also I gotta remember to look in the PRs first before starting something like this.